Wiping all data, without hard resetting my phone
I have to delete all the data on my Android device, without being able to hard reset or factory reset my phone. To explain this precarious situation, my phone has a Power button, that no longer works, my screen is barely functional, with lines across it, and the Micro USB female port, is barely functional as well, only connecting at specific angles and positions. I tried the hard reset approach, and my phone is currently stuck in a bootloop, attempting to enter Recovery Mode, only to fail and try again. I am not even sure, if it will exit this loop once the power runs out, and boot normally, but presuming it does, I will need to delete all it's data before exchanging it.
Assuming I managed to mess up the stock Recovery Mode image, recovery.img, I have devised a few approaches, that I will now mention.
Deleting and entering random data
This method involves deleting all files, and then writing random data to it. Here are the steps I have devised,

Write a shell script, to use ADB to uninstall all apps that can be uninstalled.

Delete all data from emulated storage, using ADB.

Install Termux, and fill the file system with random data, using something along the lines of,


$ dd if=/dev/random of=file bs=64k

I will be the first to admit, this is a dumb and terrible method, but it is the only one that seems mostly plausible to me. My biggest concern, after the fact that it might damage my hardware, from writing such huge files, is the fact that it might not delete the data stored in the root file system at /data. A lot of apps, especially system apps, tend to write there, like Whatsapp, and Whatsapp stores it's entire database, as well as some images there, which I am not confident will be deleted. My biggest goal, is to get all my family images and local text messages deleted.
Flashing stock recovery.img
I have considered this method, however it is unlikely to work in my case. For reasons, I was never able to unlock the bootloader of this device, and boot into fastboot mode. There is apparently a way to replace it with the stock image without booting into fastboot mode, but it requires use of the Power button.
Other options
Other options and solutions I can think of include, somehow formatting without entering Recovery Mode, or unlocking the bootloader, which should format the system. If nothing works, is having a lockscreen password enough, or can it be bypassed by the manufacturer, somehow? I know given the state of my device, it will likely be scrapped for parts, but I can never be too safe, and it feels like my duty, to do what I can.
Which, if any of these are likely to work, in my very specific and precarious situation?

My device is Realme 1 CPH1859.

adb over wifi + scrcpy might help you getting back full control of touch screen. then goto Settings - About phone - Factory reset. no other options left - you can't confirm factory reset from recovery mode without power button

I assume after deleting/overwriting your user data you want to recycle the phone? If yes then may be opening the phone and overriding the power button so you can perform a factory reset.
